# How to route traffic from the Cloudflare root domain to an AWS elastic load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloudflare, aws-application-load-balancer

My Webservers are running on AWS.

- I have created target groups and the load balancer.
- I have the ALB domain but I want to customize that DNS to the Domain that is present in Cloudflare.
- I wanna know how I can do that with the SSL certificates.
  As I am not allowed to give CNAME records for the root domain. what are the other solution for this.

**how can I route my traffic from the application load balancer to the domain present in Cloudflare?**

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare has [CNAME Flattening](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/additional-options/cname-flattening), which allows CNAME records on the root domain.

Comment: It is important to note that CNAME flattening can affect the mail services on the domain, as the root domain (e.g. example.com) will no longer have an A record, which is typically used to configure mail services.

Comment: @ashutoshMohanty can you link to any supporting documentation on that? I've never encountered that issue. Mail services typically use `MX` records, and your CNAME and A records have no bearing on email delivery at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my solution.**

First we need to go to Route53 in aws console to create new hosted zone.
Then after we create the new hosted zone as per our given details, it will create an NS and SOA record in the R53.
WE need to add those NS records in our domain registrar. and then we need to create an Alias to our DNS which  will Point to the ALB.
That's how we are able to create our customized domain name for the Application Load Balancer.

By Creating a hosted zone in R53 and adding the NS records to the domain registrar, we can delegate the DNS resolution of our custom domain to route53. Then by creating an alias to our ALB, we can map the custome domain to the ALB's DNS. This will allow us to access our ALB with our custom domain instead of using the ALB DNS.

IF THERE'S ANY OTHER SOLUTIONS THAN PLEASE FETCH YOUR ANSWERS.